# What are algebroid curves/branches and their value semigroup?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, singularity-theory

In “The moduli problem for plane branches”, by O. Zariski, the author defines a plane branch as an irreducible element $f \in \mathbb C[[x,y]]$. In the more recent article "The semigroup of a space curve singularity", by J. Castellanos, the author defines a branch/an algebroid curve as an affine scheme with the associated ring $R$ being local, Noetherian, equicharacteristic and complete (in the $\mathfrak m$-adic topology); apparently Zariski $\mapsto$ Castellanos via $f \mapsto \mathbb C[[x,y]]/(f)$. Both articles do also define the value semigroup of an algebroid curve. I do *not* know Riemann surfaces well so everything seems really weird when thinking about algebraic geometry and branches, ramification, the power series ring and irreducibility there.

I have some major questions about these concepts:

1. What is, geometrically, a branch/algebroid curve in this sense? In my naive intution, branches are something like 'uniramified' curves, where a ramification point (in complex geometry) would be  something that has two distinct analytic presentations at the point (i.e., locally  that point belongs to two distinct analytic curves). That would motivate the irreducibility hypothesis for a plane curves.
2. Where does the schematic generality come from in Castellanos' formulation? Lots of books about plane branches (for instance, E. Kunz "Introduction to Plane Algebraic Curves") talk about this "Weierstrass Preparation Theorem" for $\mathbb C[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]]$ which has a great flavor of a complex analysis/algebraic geometry correspondence, and the generalization for other rings uses, specifically, all those hypotheses for $R$.
3. What role does the completion play here? Why not work with $\mathbb C[x,y]$ or other choices for $R$? I know that the completion has an important role for the étale topology (which is a more appropriate/finer topology to work with singularities), but my knowledge about this topic is minimal.
4. Given that I don't really know the object being studied (algebroid curves), I do not know what the value semigroup is supposed to measure. What does it mean?

Extra: I asked about these things to my advisor and he said I seem to be confusing the concept of *being multiramified* ('having more than one component locally') and *being ramified at a point* ('divergence of the vanishing orders in the preimage of the cusp from the linear series'). However both of these concepts are totally strange to me. If they do appear in the definition of branch, I would really like to know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have found [this reference](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernard.teissier/documents/Triestefinal.pdf) by Teissier and it looks really clarifying. I'll keep reading and, if everything works out, I'll answer those questions.